# I have two C# apps that are exchanging data with named pipes. Is it possible to define a timeout on server side while waiting connection from client?

Tags: c#, ipc, named-pipes

I have two C# apps that are exchanging data with named pipes. App-1 is the server, App-2 is the client and both working on the same machine.

I am using the named pipes just temporarily when a specific function is triggered in App-1, and a data exchange is required between the two apps.

Due to some reasons sometimes App-2 cannot establish the connection to the pipe server (App-1). In this case the code is getting blocked and App-1 is waiting all the time for the connection.

In my usecase App-2 should make the connection let's say in 5 seconds, if not App-1 shall not wait any more for the connection and proceed with the following code lines. How can I do that?

My current code:

```cs
public void server_named_pipe()
{
    NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
        new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 20, 20);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);
    do
    {
        try
        {
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection(); // Here the code is blocked, when client cannot connect
            sw.WriteLine("Waiting");
            sw.Flush();
            pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
            test = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)                
        {
            //throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
            pipeServer.Dispose();
        }

    } 
    while (test=="");
}
```

Comment: My 2p. Will your client and server applications always exist on the same machine? If not, you're probably better switching away from named pipes and not invest the time solving problems with that. Also, you're likely better off with GRPC or even HTTP which have multi-threading and serialisation/deserialisation already solved.

Comment: @phuzi You are right. In my uscase, the client and serve are always on the same machine. The data flow is always from client to server and very lightweight (10-15 reel values). As I am from the industrial automation sector I try to find the easiest solutions when working with high language programming. After some colsuntancy, from real developers I got the suggestion to use named pipes. That's the reason why I used them.

Comment: Don't quit get it how should the server know "when" a client tries to connect and until when it should have established a connection? A server can just wait until a client connects. So when you want a 5 seconds timeout how do you know when to start that 5 seconds?

Comment: If its connected to the process start like when the process starts wait 5 seconds for a connection or end then [WaitForConnectionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.waitforconnectionasync?view=net-8.0#system-io-pipes-namedpipeserverstream-waitforconnectionasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) might be an option.

Comment: @Ralf To your question. App-1(server) is starting App-2 with some arguments and give him the job to collect some data from a specific CNC machine. At that time the pipe is intialised by App-1(server). So normally the job of  App-2 should be ready in 1-2 seconds, and App-2 as client should send the data over the pipe. I know this is an unusual case, but it is definitly known when to start the 5 seconds.

Comment: Ah., so the parent app is creating the child process and monitoring the named pipe while that child process is still doing it's thing. I think the use of client/server has lead us all down a different understanding. What you are really talking about is Inter-Process Communication (IPC). I've added the [ipc] tag for clarity.